# How do I translate this 3x3 affine transformation matrix int a 4x4 transformation matrix?

Tags: matrices, transformation, 3d, affine-geometry

I am wondering how to change the 3x3 affine transformation matrix here:

[image]

...into a 4x4 transformation matrix:

```
    ┌             ┐
T = | 1  0  0  tx |
    | 0  1  0  ty |
    | 0  0  1  tz |
    | 0  0  0   1 |
    └             ┘
```

I understand how the upper-left 3x3 of the 4x4 is for rotation and scale, how do the `a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i` of the 3x3 correspond to the positions of the 4x4. It seems like you could just copy in `a, b, d, e` in the same spots in the 4x4...but that leaves a bunch of spots unaccounted for...mainly - I know that my application scales and I would be missing an `sz` variable (see below) if I did it like that...I think.

```
    ┌               ┐
S = | sx   0   0  tx|
    |  0  sy   0  ty|
    |  0   0  sz  tz|
    |  0   0   0  1 |
    └               ┘
```

---

```
    ┌              ┐
S = |  a   b   tx  |
    |  d   e   ty  | ... with any values for a, b, d, e, s, w, tx, ty
    |  s   w   1   |
    |              |
    └              ┘

to .......

    ┌             ┐
T = | f  g  h  tx |
    | i  j  k  ty |
    | l  m  n  tz |
    | r  p  q   j |
    └             ┘
```

Connect the letters, which letters in the 3x3 goes to which letters in the 4x4 for an affine transformation (obviously tx, ty, tz are the same for both, and I know where those go)

**UPDATE**

For the comment about how the 3x3 is an affine transformation. Below is the matrix...here is a link [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221170943/http://mathforum.org/mathimages/index.php/Transformation_Matrix)
See "2D Affine Transformations"...I am essentially trying to take the 2D Affine Transformation and turn it into a 3D (4x4 matrix)...the 2D should correspond to the 3D somehow...

[image]

Comment: Please give us a simple numerical example of what you want to do.

Comment: i updated my question...putting in numbers would basically be like putting in variables for this...but it would be more confusing...I am not looking for a numerical answer, more a conceptual explanation.

Comment: How does your $3\times3$ matrix represent an *affine* transformation?

Comment: see update about how an affine transformation is represented by a  3 x 3 matrix.

Comment: i am using these for programming a transformation...i think I can just add the transforms in succession and i should be ok as long as i start with scale first..and then apply the translate...and i dont have to worry about packing it into one matrix

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no one showed interest for more than five years.